# How can I test using rails params outside controller rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I made a module in /rails_root/lib/common/common_log.rb
and included it in ApplicationController,
calling it from my controller is normally end. 
then I did rspec. but there was an error.
I can't understand how do I write params in spec file.
Please help me to solve it.

# rspec put out error

```
Failures:
  1) CommonLog log_error
     Failure/Error: log_error("xxx")
     NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `params' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1:0x3196f
50>
     # ./lib/common/common_log.rb:3:in `log_error'
     # ./spec/lib/common/common_log_spec.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

# my module file common_log.rb

```
module CommonLog
  def log_error(msg)
    Rails.logger.error "E: controller : #{params[:controller]}  action : #{params[:action]} msg=#{msg}"
  end
end
```

# my spec file

```
require 'spec_helper'
require File.expand_path("../../../../lib/common/common_log", __FILE__)
include CommonLog
describe CommonLog do
  it "log_error" do
    log_error("xxx")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use [RSpec's anonymous controller](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/controller-specs/anonymous-controller) feature.

```
  require 'spec_helper'
  require File.expand_path("../../../../lib/common/common_log", __FILE__)

  describe CommonLog, type: :controller do


  controller do
    include CommonLog
    def index
       render nothing: true
    end
  end

  it "log_error" do
    params = {param1: :value1}
    get :index, params
    #Do the specs you want here
  end
end
```

What you are doing here is creating an anonymous controller which includes the module you want to spec.
Since this module is meant to be included inside a rails controller it gives you exactly what you need: a context of controller to spec your module with.

Comment: I'm glad to see your help. this module was inside rails controller. I reached my goal with your advice. Rspec documents of anonymouse controller is usefull for me.
Thank you very much for your kindness.